# Random Paragraph, a Riddle or a Secret Message?

Tags: riddle, steganography, video-games

So, as I was playing a game, I got a weird string of messages on my screen. You think you know what the weird message means?

Pleeeeease! Don't just ignore meeeeee! ...Err.
I... I did not want to be saying this, but... Actually, you see, erm...
What, pops? You want me to tell you and gramps with the beard over there?
Surely, you aren't going to suggest I was responsible for poisoning her father, too?
Alright. Just so we're clear, dude, I didn't kill anyone,
But he was mocking me! Being mean to bullies was not included in the deal!

The game said that decoding the message would result in decoding a six letter word. The game also said that all the lines were from one particular series, but I have no guess as to what it is. Any guesses for what the secret message is?

Comment: The videogame is [Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney: Justice For All](http://aceattorney.wikia.com/wiki/Phoenix_Wright:_Ace_Attorney:_Justice_For_All), right? You have to give proper attribution for puzzles that you did not make yourself.

Comment: Well, actually the puzzle I made myself (I thought it was obvious enough), but the lines are from Ace Attorney Series. Though the puzzle and the hidden message are my work.

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer to me. I thought the whole puzzle was excerpted from a videogame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the hidden six letter word is

> rocket

Reason: all the six sentences are excerpted from the "Ace Attorney" videogame series.

> If you search for their author in http://aceattorney.wikia.com, you get:
>   1. **R**on DeLite 
>   2. **O**lga 
>   3. **C**ody 
>   4. **K**ristoph Gavin 
>   5. **E**ngarde 
>   6. **T**rilo 
>  
>  Assembling the first letter of each name gives you the hidden word.

Comment: Nice! I thought this puzzle was actually pretty hard, but you got it rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

> Pops (though I think he dies in the last one) is from the regular show (particular series) and Rigby calls Mordecai "dude" in it so it might be related to that